# HID client implement in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, hid

Can we used our iPhone as a HID client in iOS by using Bluetooth? We want to make HID communication with a Bluetooth Dongle. Our iPhone will send keys to dongle like a Keyboard, mouse , joystick etc.

The same we can done between a keyboard and a Dongle. But How it will possible when we are using ios device and dongle?

Please help to clarify my doubts If I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mohit Singhal : Have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: @VineeshTP : No, I did not. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

iOS only provides HID Host, but not HID Peripheral. You may be able to capture the keypresses in an iOS application, and send the equivalent data (ASCII or HID frames) via Bluetooth Low Energy. A custom application on the dongle/device will be required to receive the data and convert/execute to HID if desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want a small piece of code so that I can send data corresponding to keys when user press key. After connecting with a dongle , I want dongle will react to user action. Core Bluetooth works via Service UUID , Can a Dongle will provide it?